# Online Lottery Database Design

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-schema

I am trying to design a database for the known 6/49 lottery game. But I am confused about designing. First thing came up my mind is something like that:

```
Table Users:
ID | Name | Age | mail | username | password | balance | etc. |

Table Coupons :
ID | Date | Draw Date | Chose 1..6 | isWinner | owner username | earning | Cost |
```

Is that enough? Or I really want to hear new ideas. For example, after a drawing, I am going to enter results to the system. Then system has to check all the coupons which belong to relevant draw date.

However, wouldn't it be too much load if there are hundreds of thousands coupons of this particular draw date? What is the best desing for this system? Or wouldn't it be to much load when a user tries to list the coupons that s/he has played in his/her account page?

And I have to say that, I am very junior about database designing.

Comment: you would be better to have owner_id instead of owner_username on the coupons table, and join the tables appropriately as the primary key is most likely on ID and thus is already indexed and efficient as ever. And no, there shouldn't be any load issues when a user loads a page of what coupons they have. If there were any load issues, it's due to poor execution, structure, or hardware.

Comment: I hope that this is just for fun!!